# Insert variables into temp table using union all

Tags: sql, temp-tables, union-all

Why am I getting an incorrect syntax near 'dbo'. error?

```
SELECT inv_num
INTO #InvoiceList
FROM (
SELECT inv_num = 
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv1) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv2) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv3) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv4) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv5) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv6) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv7) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv8) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv9) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv10) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv11) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv12) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv13) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv14) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv15) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv16) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv17) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv18) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv19) UNION ALL
    dbo.ExpandKy(10, @Inv20)
) d
WHERE inv_num IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your union query is not valid.  It should resemble this

```
select dbo.Exandkey(10, @Inv1) invnum
union all
select dbo.Exandkey(10, @Inv2) invnum
etc
```